# Why is my controller test not working, the view name is coming back empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit

Doing a simple test to verify the view name for a controllers action:

```
  var controller = new UserController();

  var result = controller.Login() as ViewResult;

  Assert.AreEqual("Login", result.ViewName);
```

The result.ViewName is coming back with "", why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifying the view name in the controller Login method or are you leaving it at the default value (which is "")?

If you leaving it at the default value, which is common, you need to test for String.Empty instead of "Login".

Comment: Yes default value, oh I see so it resolves the name further down the stack then ok thanks.

Comment: Yes. And sorry I forgot to mention that. The replacement doesn't take place until the view is getting rendered which is later in the processing stream.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a view like this

```
 public ActionResult Index()
  {
   return View();
  }
```

then the ViewName property will take it's default value that is "" and if you specify the view name like this it'll work fine

```
 public ActionResult Index()
  {
   return View("Index");
  }
```